# Filter a django QuerySet with the query from another QuerySet: Possible?

Tags: django, django-models

Say I create a QuerySet like:

```
q0  = Thing.objects.all()
fq0 = q0.filter(x=y)
```

at time t0. Then I add some new things to Thing db. These things form the QuerySet:

```
q1 = Thing.objects.filter(created_gt=t0)
```

I want to generate the QuerySet:

```
fq = (q0 | q1).filter(x=y)
```

Without having to know what x or y are.  In other words, i'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
fq1 = q1.filter(query=fq0.query)
fq = fq0 | fq1
```

Is this possible? Manually setting

```
q1.query = fq0.query
```

merely sets `q1 == fq0`. I've seen some people asking about extracting the sql from a queryset, but this won't really help me.

Answer (score 32):

How about something along these lines:

```py
Thing.objects.filter(field__in=Another_Thing.object.filter())
```

Django will do query and subquery.

Comment: I think you mean `Another_model.objects.filter()` or just `another_queryset`.

Answer (score 1):

Many year after I found a solution.

You can use the `__dict__` prop from you queryset. For instance:

```
o = Model.objects.filter(arg=param)
o2 = Model.objects.all()
o2.query.__dict__ = o.query.__dict__
o2.filter(arg2=param2)
```

o2 will now is filtered by arg and arg2!

I used this to pass a ModelChoiceField filter to django-jet autocomplete views (fork at https://github.com/paulorsbrito/django-jet).

Hope this helps someone in trouble.

Comment: It's never a good idea to mess with `__*__` fields, they are internals.

Comment: I disagree. If they were internals and should not be touched, then python should have been designed like java ou c++. That's python!

Comment: I just said it was a bad idea, I didn't said that you shouldn't do it... ;)
People using those internals on objects they don't manage should know what it implies.

There are so many bug reports on famous libs because the team changed some internals and it broke some external code using it!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from looking through the QuerySet and Query modules, Django doesn't keep a running record of the arguments you send into a queryset. It translates everything directly into lower level query fragments then discards the tokens you've given it. Thus, figuring out how a queryset has been filtered without prior knowledge is a non-trivial task.

You could do it manually by hacking together something like the following:

```
q0 = Thing.objects.all()
filter_kwargs = {'x': y}
fq0 = q0.filter(**filter_kwargs)
fq0.saved_filter_kwargs = filter_kwargs

##### snip #####

fq1 = q1.filter(**fq0.saved_kwargs)
```

Kind of nasty though. Probably better to try solving this problem in a different way. I'd recommend you post another question and include what you're trying to achieve in the big picture, and we might be able to help you come up with a better architecture.

Comment: Big picture: cache fq0, generate fq by filtering q1 only. You're right that this is a nasty solution. It becomes even nastier when you're caching things. Luckily I did find a better solution. Thanks for your help though. I'd upvote you but I need more rep.

Comment: @dmrparthenon you should answer your question with the solution you found to help comunity and mark as resolved answer your own answer.